# is it possible in Apache Cayenne to prepopulate an ObjectContext without a database?

Tags: apache-cayenne

I am evaluating Cayenne for some new projects.

I wonder if it is possible (for unit tests) to use Cayenne without a database and instead somehow prepopulate an ObjectContext from data I obtain from a file to reach an identical state as if it was read from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory yes, but practically this is too much trouble to implement. A much easier approach is to use an in-memory DB like Apache Derby. Frameworks like Bootique.io [provide assistance](https://twitter.com/andrus_a/status/1172197533147439104) with starting/stopping Derby and populating it with data, but this can be done on your own as well with a bit of effort.

Comment: Thanks Andrus, 
that should probably be suitable for me for mere before state population. 
Best regards, 
Robert